# Add external configuration in "Run As" menu

Tags: eclipse, run-configuration

I have created an external configuration to run my program, and now to run it I have to click on `"Run" menu on the top ->External Tools -> my configuration`. 
I was wondering if there's a way to avoid this and run this configuration directly from the `Run As` menu that pops out from right clicking project.

Comment: The Toolbar has a Run External Tools button where you can set up favourites to appear in the drop down menu.

Comment: @greg-449 yes but I would like to have it also in the right-click menu from the project -> run as -> my configuration

Comment: @greg-449 I mean, I've already set it as favourite, but it doesn appear in the run as menu from the project

Comment: As far as I know that is all there is